# Computing the image of a regular map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the regular map $f: \mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2$  defined by $f(x,y)= (x,xy)$. Find the image $f(\mathbb{A}^2)$. Is it open in $\mathbb{A}^2$? Is it dense? Is it closed?

I really don’t know how to tackle this problem and I think I’m not even understanding what it’s asking: isn’t the image already described by $f(\mathbb{A}^2) = \left\{ (x,xy) : x,y \in \mathbb{A}^1 \right\}$? Any help would be very appreciated, thank you

Comment: Related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919793/polynomial-vanishing-on-mathbba2), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731178/what-can-we-say-about-the-image-of-a-regular-map), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799642/example-of-two-affine-varieties-x-y-such-that-the-image-of-phix-rightarrow), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168526/about-the-image-of-a-morphism-of-algebraic-sets). This is almost a duplicate of each of the above, but maybe not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if $x=0$, then $(x,xy) = (0,0)$. So, the only point of the image lying on the $y$-axis is the origin. However, if $x \neq 0$, we can choose $y$ to make $xy$ take any value in $\mathbb{A}^1$. Therefore, the image can be described as
$$
f(\mathbb{A}^2) = \mathbb{A}^2 - (V(x) - \{(0,0)\}). 
$$
Since $V(x) - \{(0,0)\}$ is neither open nor closed, $f(\mathbb{A}^2)$ is neither. However, it is dense.

Notice that this image can be expressed as a union of $\mathbb{A}^2 - V(x)$ and $\{(0,0)\}$. So, it is the union of an open set and a closed set, and is therefore *constructible* (i.e. it is a finite union of *locally closed sets*, those which can be written as the intersection of a closed set and an open set). That images of maps of algebraic varieties have this property is a theorem of Chevellay.

Comment: Very clear, thank you. One last question: why is it dense?

Comment: @cip It contains the non-empty open set $\mathbb{A}^2 - V(x)$, and all non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb{A}^2$ are dense ($\mathbb{A}^2$ is irreducible).

Comment: Ok, I see. It suffices to have just one dense subset of $f(\mathbb{A}^2)$ to conclude that $f(\mathbb{A}^2)$ is dense, right? I think that is true by definition of density?

Comment: @cip Yes. In general, if $S \subset T$ is an inclusion of subsets of any space, then there is an inclusion $\overline{S} \subset \overline{T}$ of closures.